# Returning a generic Interface with concrete implementation in java

Tags: java, generics, maven

I have a generic Interface which is implemented by a class, that I want to return in a generic method.
Interface:

```
public interface IWorker<T extends Object, K extends Object> {  
public K doWork(T o);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class WorkerImpl implements IWorker<String, List<Serializable>>
{
   @Override
   public List<Serializable> doWork(String s)
   {
       return ...
   }
}
```

ActionCoordinator Interface for the generic method returning the implementation:

```
public interface IActionCoordinator
{
    public <T extends Serializable, K extends Serializable> IWorker<T, K> getAction(T  request);
}
```

ActionCoordinator implementation:

```
public class ActionCoordinatorImpl implements IActionCoordinator
{
    @Override
    public <T extends Serializable, K extends Serializable> IWorker<T, K> getAction(final T requ)
    {
        return (IWorker<T,K>)new WorkerImpl();
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
In eclipse this will work, but doing a maven build with the JDK 1.6.0_35 doesn't and says "inconvertible types". I can get around with that:

```
public class ActionCoordinatorImpl implements IActionCoordinator
{
    @Override
     public <T extends Serializable, K extends Serializable> IWorker<T, K> getAction(final T requ)
    {
        Object temp = new WorkerImpl();
        return (IWorker<T,K>)temp;
    }
}
```

But that it's not supposed to be, that wouldn't be type-safe at all.

Some ideas would be nice. Thanks in advance...

**EDIT: What works for me now is the following:**
I changed all the generic Ts and Ks to be Serializable. Thats all what I needed to restrict the WorkerImpl to be. the actual caller still needs an `IWorker<T,K>` but `IWorker<Serializable,Serializable>` fits and works...thanks everyone, but I still wonder why eclipse is not saying anything...

Comment: The last one is not less safe than the previous one. Both do the same thing. What if I do `actionCoordinatorImpl<Integer, Integer>.getAction(0)`?

Comment: Neither version appears to be type safe. And `javac` is right to complain.

Comment: Are you sure it works in Eclipse? If it is a java issue (and "inconvertible types" points to it), it should fall in both).

Comment: yes eclipse unfortunatly compiles and runs it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that maven *won't* compile, it's that Eclipse isn't complaining about an unsafe cast: You probably have an option turned off in your Eclipse preferences and are doing a strict compile in maven.

Your `WorkerImpl` is unsuitable to return from your factory method in `ActionCoordinatorImpl`, because there's no guarantee that the `Serializable` passed to its `doWork()` method will be a `String` - it just has to be any `Serializable`.

Also, you could simplify your code by changing `IWorker` from

```
public interface IWorker<T extends Object, K extends Object>
```

to

```
public interface IWorker<T, K>
```

Since they are equivalent (everything extends Object)

Comment: Good catch! I was pointing at type erasure but I like your answer better.

Comment: Is there a way to do it type-safe?

Comment: @peatle_pp No. You'll either need to type `ActionCoordinatorImpl`, effectively making it an abstract factory, or pass in `class` objects for `T` and `K` and use `instanceof` to determine which impl of `Worker` to return, but this second option will still require an "unsafe" cast as far as the compiler's concerned (but it won't be unsafe because you've checked the type in code). Overall, I'd say your design needs simplifying - without looking at it too deeply, it seems you have too many layers going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WorkerImpl` only implements `IWorker<String, List<Serializable>>`. You then try to make it an `IWorker<T extends Serializable, K extends Serializable>` in `ActionCoordinatorImpl` which is not correct and should be reported as an error.

It would be difficlt to recommend a fix until you are clear what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks...I would like to get an `IActionCoordinator` and call the `getAction()` to get me an `IWorker<T extends Serializable, K extends Serializable>`. with this Worker i can run the `doWork()` method. The caller does not have to know what exactly the WorkerImpl is doing.

Answer (score 0):

`new WorkerImpl()` yields `IWorker<String, List<Serializable>>`, how are you going to convert it to  `IWorker<T,K>`? And where do you think compiler should get the type `K`? Will you always pass it explicitly when invoking `getAction`? Then you have to pass type `T` also, but it is also set by the parameter `requ`, and the invocation would look ugly.